# Suggesting or requesting that people nominate themselves in a moderator election

Tags: discussion, meta, moderators, moderator-election

Several years ago, [Grace Note wrote in the 2015 Code Review Moderation Election chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22457226#22457226):

> Some sites like to host a thread where people can try to goad others into nominating by naming them and saying "Oi I think you should run for these very many awesome reasons"

I assume Grace Note knows what they're talking about, since they're a staff member. However, I was not able to find any such post on Stack Overflow Meta. Do we have one? Did I just miss it?

If Stack Overflow Meta does not have one of these posts, why not? Should it? Is it due to the size of Stack Overflow that there will always be enough users nominating that such a post wouldn't be necessary? Or maybe I'm overthinking it, and any user can create such a post *(as long as it hasn't been created yet)* as long as they want to?

Comment: I don't think it's such a good idea to publicly encourage people to nominate themselves. It's an unpaid challenging job. Picking people out might feel them pressured and unnecessarily put in the spotlight. There might be circumstances in their lives that you don't know about that would prevent them from running. Wait for their nominations, and then you can publicly endorse them with comments under their nomination posts.

Comment: People need to *volunteer* to be called out in public. If you want to reach out to specific people whom you already know, and encourage them to run, then go ahead and do so. I've done so many times in the past.

Comment: People need to want to be a moderator enough to consider it without being pressured by an upvoted meta Answer with their name on it. Moderators should really want the "job". Then they are more likely to be enthusiastic enough to keep up the daily exception handling :)

Comment: Trying to lure people into jobs full of hard work without adequate payment is kind of not very ethical behavior. Even other sites shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 19):

Moderator elections are self-nominate for a reason.  If a person chooses to run, then they get to make the conscious choice to participate.  If a person chooses *not* to run, then they don't have to think about how the others Really Feel About Them™ as they carry on their lives as normal people.

So...don't worry about it?  Let them volunteer for the popularity contest and obligatory janitor role of their own volition, and do your best to suss out the ones who wouldn't do well in that position.

Comment: I appreciate the point about "how others Really Feel About Them™". I had assumed that this would, worst case, solicit positive feedback that nobody would mind receiving, even if they don't have the time or interest in being a moderator. But now that I think about it, that could also result in people elevating counterarguments that would be unwelcome and counterproductive. That's certainly not something I have interest in promoting. Thank you, as always, for your thoughtful response.