# Is it appropriate to post on meta on why we think one particular existing candidate would be a great moderator?

Tags: discussion, meta, moderator-election

There have been plenty of examples where users post on meta to highlight the good deeds of other users, and such posts are usually well-received by the community.

It's also the case that [Suggesting or requesting that people nominate themselves in a moderator election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412248) is frowned upon.

However, is posting about a user who has already nominated themselves acceptable? This would be a way to campaign for the candidate we want to see elected as moderator. Or would it be unfair to the other candidates who might have equally proven themselves, but without a user posting about them?

Comment: Promoting a particular candidate isn't a question about the software that powers the network or relevant to the day to day operation of SO.

Comment: It's the choice of the person if they want to put themselves up as a candidate to be moderator, not the community; the community just elects those who put themselves up for candidacy.

Comment: @KevinB True, but what about all the "Goodbye" posts and the "Thank you" posts?

Comment: @AnnZen It is my opinion that they should all be closed.

Comment: @Larnu Note I wrote *existing* candidates, not a user who didn't nominate.

Comment: I don't really feel that changes my point, @AnnZen . It's the user who nominated themselves, and up to them to explain why, in my opinion.

Comment: I think we usually close all GoodBye posts as off-topic. The only exception is moderator stepdowns which are on-topic

Comment: @Larnu There might have been many small incidents that proves their reliability & patience that they didn't bring them up in their nomination post *(which can also be a sign of humbleness)*. I don't see why another user who feels strongly about them shouldn't be able to highlight their actions.

Comment: I don't know how to vote on this question: I think the question is relevant, but I don't want to imply that I'm in favor of promoting a candidate (the voting system seems to be used that way a lot on meta).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thanks for your consideration! I mean, I'm not asking *for* it to be allowed, just *if* it is allowed :)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I also don't think it's a good idea to campaign for nominees on meta, and I voted up this question, because as far as I can tell, the question is not taking a stand either way, and it's nice to have a meta question addressing whether the community thinks this should be allowed.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny A discussion is just that - a discussion. If you think the question is well-asked and useful, then vote up. Then, find (or write) an answer that describes your opinion as it relates to the question asked. I know that there's this feeling that you downvote questions to show disagreement but that's really only supposed to be used on feature requests (and I'm not really sure I still agree with that practice any more, anyway)...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, why?

There are already options to "campaign" for a candidate:

- leave a comment under their nomination
- leave a message in the Election chat.

We don't need *more* places to scatter the info about candidates.

And you're meaning well by campaigning *for* a candidate but if we allow that we for sure should also see posts to campaign *against* a particular candidate.

We can't have nice things. Let's not open-up meta (drama) for these kind of posts. It has little effect, if any, and I can dream-up reasons to cause negative side-effects.

Comment: *"We don't need more places to scatter the info about candidates."* - Indeed, I'm sure plenty people already don't read the comments, why would they read a separate meta post

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine Actually, I believe a separate meta post would be noticed way more than a comment among the long thread of comments.

Comment: I think it would too, but that'd be problematic; the path to being elected shouldn't effectively require cluttering up meta during the election.

Comment: @rene - So this wouldn't be the appropriate place to suggest you would be a good moderator? Asking for a friend.

Answer (score -6):

## No, the format would bias the election

> is posting about a user who has already nominated themselves acceptable?

No, this would be unbalanced because we don't accept public criticism about people and their actions on the network, and without that it would create and further an *illusion* that isn't productive. What would it look like to have a candidate discussed on a Q/A forum? Answers that are positive and bolster the candidate are accepted and upvoted, and answers that demonstrate controversy or problematic behavior are deleted for being unkind, and targeted? I can't see that conversation being productive.

Comment: I agree with No, but not quite with the rest. First, there is nothing in the format that could bias election, definitely not more than current format can. If anything, comments can be deleted and they are no longer visible to regular users and deleted answers are visible to high reputation users. Also I don't see why would exposing problematic behavior be targeted in negative way. We had example in last elections where one candidate was removed from the elections and that discussion happened on Meta in additional posts.

Comment: So, No as general rule stays as we don't need scattered discussion, but there are always exceptional situations that would warrant such discussion.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Indeed it happened. If it happened in a good way is not so clearcut though. The current state of the announcement post is quite respectable but I don't know how much pruning has been done there to get it to that state.

Comment: @Gimby I am not saying what happened and how was all great, but overall I think it was a good example how Meta as a collective is capable of navigating troubled waters. If there is a need to discuss something I think Meta can handle such discussions constructively.